# Purchase Event - Tag fires but the parameters are blank in GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have being trying to set up the GA4 purchase event.

The purchase event fires but no data gets populated in the parameters.

Below is the Data Layer results that I see in Tag Assistant...

[Data Layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fj7mC.jpg)

Below is what is shown in the parameters...
[Tag Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYr5O.jpg)

I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

The gray boxes are variable names. You have to click on 'values' in the upper right corner in your GTM debug viewer.[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGt6o.png)